# Why am I getting an Unexpected TOKEN Illegal error in my jQuery script?

Tags: jquery, django

I added a basic script at the end of my template that calculates the characters remaining and displays it live, as seen here. http://jsfiddle.net/r34gM/1/

It does not seem to be working, I don't see anything updating, and I'm getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Here is the template.

```
<div class="background2div">
    <div class="backgroundiv">
    <div class="formdiv">
        <div class="selltitle">Sell Goodies</div>
        <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" data-parsley-validate> 
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="forminput">{{ form.body_text }}</div></div>
        <div class="suggest2">Describe in detail what makes this product worth buying.</div>
        <div class="suggest7">250 character limit</div>
        <div class="linecontainer"><div class="forminput"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#id_body_text').keypress(function(){

    if(this.value.length > 160){
        return false;
    }
    $(".suggest7").html("Remaining characters : " +(160 - this.value.length));
});​
</script>
```

Comment: Take the code (and only the JS code) into a browser JS repl. Then simplify it until the syntax error is found.

Comment: (Hint: there is an *invalid character* at the very end that cannot be seen.)

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Press F12 - then an appropriate developer tool should open. REPL = "JavaScript Console".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unicode character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B) in you source code.

```
<script>
$('#id_body_text').keypress(function(){

    if(this.value.length > 160){
        return false;
    }
    $(".suggest7").html("Remaining characters : " +(160 - this.value.length));
}); // <--- HERE IS THE (U+200B) AFTER THE ';'!
</script>
```

Delete this char and all will work fine.

Comment: I have no idea how you found that, or how to delete it.  I do not see // in the script.  How do I delete it?

Comment: `//` is the my comment :-) Delete the whole `});` line and type it again.

Comment: When I delete that, Chrome gives me  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: As I said. Delete the **whole** line and **retype** it again.  Wrong symbol is right behind `;` char.

Comment: Okay, I deleted and retyped and it works now.  I don't understand why, I have no idea why that would change anything, but thank you.